# Rails 3: where query issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am learning about 'where' in Rails 3 and I am wondering why my code is giving me a NoMethod Error.

```
  def create
    #get form values from 'new' page
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])

    #search for the inventory item with the sku code the user typed in the form
    @item = Inventory.where(:sku_code => @post.sku_code)

    #set post variable to a variable from the row with the sku code
    @post.detail = @item.detail

    @post.save
  end
```

By searching the SKU, I want to retrieve the other variables in the same id and set them to my  @post variable. Anyone able to give me a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that SKU code is unique, you got to do it like this

```
@post = Post.new(params[:post])

@post.detail = Inventory.where(:sku_code => @post.sku_code).first.try(:detail)
```

`first` will fetch the first (and possibly only) record from the database. `try` will try to fetch `detail` if the returned `Inventory` was not nil.

Check [this blog post](http://everydayrails.com/2011/04/28/rails-try-method.html) to learn more about `try` method.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I checked the references and they are correct. It is giving me a Template is missing error:
Missing template posts/create, application/create.

Any ideas?

Comment: Usually you want to redirect after creation, for example to the show action. Or show the form again by rendering new if the post cannot be saved. See as well http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-new-posts